# Probability of scoring a double century with a boundary

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, word-problem

A cricketer is having a lucky day today. On every ball he faces the batsman scores either 1,2,3 or 4 runs each with equal probability of 0.25. Assume that the batsman does not get out and there are infinite overs in game play. What is the probability that the cricketer scores a double century(>=200 runs) with a boundary (that is by hitting 4 runs).

Attempt- Intuitively I thought that once the player reaches 196, 197, 198 or 199 he just needs to score a boundary with probability=0.25 and, P(reaching 196,197,198 or 199)=1, so required probability should be 0.25. But this is not the answer

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983121/probability-to-get-200-or-more-with-a-4?noredirect=1#comment4071001_1983121

Comment: As I point out in my comment to the earlier posting of this question, the answer you want turns out to be $p_{200}$, the probability of hitting $200$ exactly.  Indeed both the answer and this probability are equal to $\frac 14\times \left(p_{199}+p_{198}+p_{197}+p_{196}\right)$.  It is "easy" to solve for $p_{200}$ recursively...it turns out that $p_n\to .4$ quite quickly.

Comment: @lulu the other question had no additional effort or explanation. Jashan has made a (naïve but legitimate) attempt before asking. If anything, the other is a duplicate here.

Comment: @Nij  Sure.  I didn't vote to close this question (nor the other one) for that reason.  Worth pointing out:  your solution below is only approximate (though it is very accurate) as there are small differences in the probabilities of reaching the prior states.  If you replace $200$ by something a lot smaller, these differences matter...in this case it's negligible, though you really need to argue that fact.

Comment: The original wording is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972512/double-century-with-a-four/2972698#2972698 but the expanded interpretation of them both is different. Overall, there's an interpretation question of whether this is: A: Hit 196 and roll a 4 or B: Hit 196-199 and roll a 4 or C: Hit 200 exactly by rolling any number. C seems excluded but A and B have different answers.

Answer (score 0):

If no score below 196 can make the double century, then only the scores from 196 to 199 need be considered. Because the number of ways of achieving a number by summing elements in ${1,2,3,4}$ freely chosen is really big after comparatively few elements are summed, the probabilities that each of these numbers is our starting point are almost identical, so we'll act like they're all equally likely.

- 196, there is only one way to make it: a four. The other three balls take the batsman to one of the next scores.
- 197, either a three or a four will get there. This gives us two ways by a four and once by a three, so far.
- 198, a single won't do, the rest can. That's three fours, two threes, and one two as an outcome.
- 199, it wouldn't matter what he gets. That's now one way by a one, two ways by a two, three by a three, and four ways by a four.

This is a total of ten ways to achieve the double century, so the probability it happens as a boundary is $$P=\frac{4}{10}=0.4$$

Comment: But how can you say that scoring a four from 196 is the same as scoring a four from 199. I mean shouldn't we take into account the probability of reaching 196 or 199 for that matter?

Comment: @JashanSinghal: The probability of reaching any particular score in the hundreds is very close to $0.4$.  So you get $0.4\times\frac14+0.4\times\frac14+0.4\times\frac14+0.4\times\frac14 = 0.4$

Comment: @Henry what is this, overtime?! We only play four quarters to one match around here! ;)

Comment: @Nij: I have heard it said that $4=5$ for sufficiently large values of $4$.  I have edited my previous comment

Comment: Indeed, $4=6$ if you're allowed to pick which four you get...