# Double century with a four

Tags: probability

Virat Kohli playing innings of his life. There are infinite overs. On each ball, he can score either 1, 2, 3,  or 4 runs with equal probability. What is the probability that he will score a double century with a boundary?

Rephrased version:A rabbit is at the bottom of the staircase with 200 steps, each time the rabbit can take 1,2,3 or 4 steps with equal probability. What is the probability that the rabbit will reach the 200th step with a step jump of size 4?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Can you rephrase it using more standard terms?

Comment: Are you just saying "you get $1,2,3,4$ each trial with equal probability and keep track of the sum.  What is the probability that at some point the sum is exactly $200$?"

Comment: Define inning, over, century, boundary in this context

Comment: Just for more context what I understand - A batsman is playing cricket, they can score 1,2,3,4 run each ball with equal probability.
The Question he's asking is - what is the probability that the batsman score 200 run with a boundary(4 runs) i.e. the batsman has 196-199 runs and scores a boundary to reach 200

Comment: Yup! 4 runs = A boundary

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what is being asked.

Comment: scores a boundary means how can he score 200 runs with the last run being a 4.

Comment: This was a Goldman Sachs interview question in our IIT.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: A rabbit is at the bottom of the staircase with 200 steps, each time the rabbit can take 1,2,3 or 4 steps with equal probability. What is the probability that the rabbit will reach the 200th step with a step jump of size 4?

Comment: Sure Sir...Pr(Goes from 196 to 200 in one event)<---this is what I am asking

Comment: @AbhishekPaul: Do you folks not have sixes over there?  In general, you can't assume that most of the readership has more of a familiarity with cricket beyond knowing it exists.  I know a bit about it, and I never call a four a "boundary"; I call it a "four."  (That's not a claim of anything more than my own ignorance, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*BIG CAVEAT*: These numbers are actually "infinitesimally close". See note below.

The probability is $\frac{1}{10}$.

There are two methods to see this.
First, we can calculate the probability of landing on 196 by a long iterative process that is easily done in a spreadsheet. 
The probability of starting at 0 is 1.
The probability of landing on 1 is $\frac{1}{4}$.
The probability of landing on 2 is the probability of rolling there from zero directly ($\frac{1}{4}$) or of hitting one and then rolling a 1 ($\frac{1}{16}$).
We can continue this process until we get to four, where we can simplify it as $\frac{1}{4}$ times the sum of the previous four rows.
If we do this formula and then repeat it down to 196, we see see that very quickly, the probability of landing on any given number is $\frac{4}{10}$. If we land on 196, we have a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance to roll a 4 and fulfill the conditions. Thus, $\frac{4}{10}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{10}$.

Second method:
Let us assume we hit 200 or went over after this process and examine the pairs (previous number, final roll): {(196,4),(197,3),(197,4),(198,2),(198,3),(198,4),(199,1),(199,2),(199,3),(199,4)}. There are ten of them, and I argue that they're equally likely.

NOTE ABOUT "CLOSE": The probability of each step is not actually 0.4. It is very close. The probability of hitting 0...4 is $1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{16},\frac{25}{64},\frac{125}{256}$ respectively. They then start approaching 0.4 as a limit.

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your solution, but assuming your ten pairs are a correct and exhaustive listing, I would guess that the probability is not *exactly* $1/10$, but probably within an extremely small margin of $1/10$.  I don't recall if there's an elegant way of determining what the exact deviation is.

Comment: @BrianTung You're correct. The probability converges towards uniformity of 0.4 on each number fairly quickly, but it is a limit, and so infinitesimally close. If you use the spreadsheet method I noted above, you can see how quickly it converges. By 196, it's indistinguishable from 0.4 for standard calculations.